# What is the meaning of BCH address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I found one more address link in my zebpay wallet is called bch address. But I don't know what is it.

- What is meaning of bch address?
- Where to get bch address?
- Where to use bch address?

Answer (score 1):

If you have had bitcoin in zebpay wallet on August 1st, You should have an equal amount of BCH(bitcoin cash). Zebpay wants to send this amount to you.

If you want a BCH wallet, You can install electron wallet from https://electroncash.org/ get a public address and submit it to zebpay. They will send your BCH to you.

Note that if you did not have Bitcoin in zebpay wallet as of August 1st , you may not receive anything.

Comment: bitcoin cash means real money..?

Comment: It is also a cryptocurrency like litecoin,ethereum etc.  https://www.bitcoincash.org/ .

Comment: Means both are different, then where shell i use that bch amount..?

Comment: you can convert it to btc via shapeshift etc. or just hold bch(like ltc, doge etc.)